# Row calculation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

Hi all,

Let's say for example I have 4 rows here A, B, C, and D with 3 columns SRG, PTS and ACSP.
The 4th row "D" is a calculation of C/A (C divided by A). Need help in performing this calculation in Power BI.

Answer (score -1):

Right click in your fields pane on your table `New Column` and use following  DAX expression:

```
= DIVIDE([C], [A])
```